# ubuntu 12.10 can't find java, but it's exists!

Tags: java, paths

I installed ZendStudio 5.5.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 and it runs well , no problem.
Today, I download Ubuntu 12.10 and intalled it on my / but keep the /home partition.
And now, I can't run the ZendStudio any more, it gives me this error:

> strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file
>   ./ZDE: 1714: exec: /home/william/Zend/ZendStudio-5.5.1/jre/bin/java: not found

But the java file exist! What's wrong? Thanks!

I fixed the problem ,it's because I am using 64bit OS and after I run

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 lib32stdc++6 lib32asound2 ia32-libs libc6-i386 lib32gcc1
```

The Zend Studio 5.5.1 can run now.

Answer (score 1):

is java installed in general?
to find out just run

`java -version`

it should print out something like

```
java version "1.7.0_07"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.2) (7u7-2.3.2a-1ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
```

if this is the lib file is just not in place anymore, you should probably check where the file is located at and create a link to it

you can use the find command to do this

`find /lib{/,32/} -name "libc.so.6"`

if you found the file just create a symbolic link to it and you should be good to go

`sudo ln -s /path/to/real/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6`

edit:

to fix the missing java run

`whereis java`

which should print out something like **/usr/bin/java**

now start ZDE using the parameter **LAX_VM**, so it should look like this

`./ZDE LAX_VM=/usr/bin/java`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did what you said above and now the message "strings: '/lib/libc.so.6': No such file" disappared, but "./ZDE: 1714: exec: /home/william/Zend/ZendStudio-5.5.1/jre/bin/java: not found" is still there and my ZendStudio still can't work

Comment: find out where your java executable is, use "whereis java", this command should print out the path to the java file.
lets asume its /usr/bin/java, now run ./ZDE LAX_VM=/usr/bin/java

Comment: But, ZendStudio has his own jre inside, so ZS should use that one, not /usr/bin/java, right?

Comment: It has its own jre in case the system has no java, there is no actual need to use that specific java version, it just simplifies the installation of it, you can also install it with the LAX_VM parameter, so it'll use the systems jre, long story short, it basically just tells ZDE which java to use, thats it.

Comment: Thank you Stefan! I run "whereis java", it gives me " java: /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/X11/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz ", and I tried " ./ZDE LAX_VM=/usr/bin/java ", it gave me same error: " ./ZDE: 1714: exec: /home/william/Zend/ZendStudio-5.5.1/jre/bin/java: not found ", it seems like ZDE only want to use the jre inside it, and the java file does exist, but it said "not found", which is really strange...